# Deploying React App on IIS8 Windows server (Azure VM)

Tags: reactjs, iis, deployment, react-router

Please help. I have a react app which works perfectly when launched from VS2017. The same app when hosted on Azure VM (IIS-8, Windows Server) gives me 404 or 500 errors.

My hosting directory structure works for my .Net app and mixed .net and React apps but not for my new React only app.

My directory structure is wwwroot>Dashboard. I copy my production build to this dashboard folder.

My webconfig is:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
          <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>
            <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Dashboard.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
            <rewrite>
                    <rules>
                        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                            <match url=".*" />
                                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                                </conditions>
                            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                        </rule>
                    </rules>
                </rewrite>
            </system.webServer>
        </location>
    </configuration>`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUwbk.png)

Comment: Could you please share your IIS web application structure image? Does your web application contain a netcore/react app and a other react application? The url rewrite rule seems let all the request go to the default page except three spcial conditions.

Comment: Please see screenshot from the link above. It won't allow me to embed image. Yes, our app is netcore/react app.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the asp.net core application use services.AddSpaStaticFiles to serve React application instead of using url rewrite.

I suggest you could check the Startup.cs's Configure and ConfigureServices method to make sure you have added the SPA settings.

Codes as below:

```
     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            //the source path of the react application
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If you use this setting, there is no need to add url rewrite rule. I suggest you could try to remove the rule. If it show 500 error, please post the details error message about the 500 error.